# What is required for a Mach-O executable to load?

Tags: mach-o, xnu

I am attempting to hand-write a Mach-O executable. There are three load commands:

- `LC_SEGMENT_64` loading `__PAGEZERO`
- `LC_SEGMENT_64` loading `__TEXT`, with a single `__text` section
- `LC_UNIXTHREAD` with an appropriately-set `rip`

Every command matches the structs in `mach/loader.h` and related headers. `otool -l` lists the information as expected and doesn't report any errors. By all accounts it is a well-formed object file — yet OS X 10.10.5 terminates the task (SIGKILL).

What features of a Mach-O executable are checked before OS X will load it? Where is this information located? Do these features change version-to-version? (The often-cited "OS X ABI Mach-O Reference" is apparently missing.)

---

Here is a [partially annotated hexdump](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wirelyre/e5b9ba70eb75e1a47f83f7e8aa2bdbe8/raw/) of the binary.

`otool` sanity check (excerpted):

```
$ otool -l machtest
machtest:
Load command 0
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __PAGEZERO
…
Load command 1
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 152
  segname __TEXT
…
Section
  sectname __text
   segname __TEXT
…
Load command 2
        cmd LC_UNIXTHREAD
…
```

Comment: Also, would it be appropriate to post an annotated hexdump? I didn't because it's 100 lines long, but they're all relevant to the question.

Comment: Sharing a hexdump would be useful.

Comment: Haven't had time to sift through it yet, but [found a re-up of the "OS X ABI Mach-O File Format Reference"](https://pewpewthespells.com/re/Mach-O_File_Format.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since 10.10.5 Yosemite, the executable file must be at least **4096** bytes long ( `PAGE_SIZE` ), or it will be killed immediately. The relevant code found by @Siguza in the `XNU kernel` `exec_activate_image` function https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/kern/kern_exec.c#L1456

## Without dyld

Assuming you want a 64-bit macOS executable using only system calls, you need:

- Mach-O 64-bit Header
- `LC_SEGMENT_64` `__PAGEZERO` (with nonzero size, name can be anything)
- `LC_SEGMENT_64` `__TEXT` (name can be anything; must be readable and executable; sections are optional)
- `LC_UNIXTHREAD`

Here is [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453849/minimal-mach-o-64-binary/32659692#32659692) for this case.

## With dyld

You can't do much without dyld though, so if you want to use it the minimal set is:

- Mach-O 64-bit Header
- `LC_SEGMENT_64` `__PAGEZERO` (with nonzero size)
- `LC_SEGMENT_64` `__TEXT` (name can be anything; must be readable and executable; sections are optional)
- `LC_SEGMENT_64` `__LINKEDIT` (must be writable because dyld requires a writable segment, in a `ld` linked binary the writable segment typically would be `__DATA`)
- `LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY` (specifies where the actual `dyld` load commands physically are in the executable, typically they will be found `__LINKEDIT` but there's no limitation on this) or interestingly `LC_SYMTAB` instead, which would make the actual `dyld` impossible to use without `LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY`.
- `LC_DYSYMTAB` (this can be empty)
- `LC_LOAD_DYLINKER`
- `LC_MAIN` or `LC_UNIXTHREAD`
- `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` (at least one actual dylib to load that eventually depends on libSystem or libSystem itself for `LC_MAIN` to work)

Additionally since MacOS Monterey 12.3:

- `LC_SYMTAB` (which is now required if `LC_DYSYMTAB` is used)

## `LC_UNIXTHREAD` and `LC_MAIN`

In modern executables (since 10.7 Mountain Lion), `LC_UNIXTHREAD` is replaced by `LC_MAIN`, which requires `dyld` — but `LC_UNIXTHREAD` is still supported for any executable as of 10.12 Sierra (and it should be in future MacOS versions, because it's utilised by `dyld` executable itself to actually start).

For `dyld` to work the extra steps depend on type of binding:
`bind at load` is the least effort approach , where `LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY` pointing to valid `dyld load commands` pointing to writable segment will do the trick.
`lazy binding` additionally requires extra platform specific code in `__TEXT` which utilises binded at load time `dyld_stub_binder` to lazy load address of a `dyld` loaded function.
There are other types of `dyld binding` which I don't cover here.

Further details can be found here: https://github.com/opensource-apple/dyld/blob/master/src/ImageLoaderMachO.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but you will need `LC_LOAD_DYLINKER` load command to run dyld before your executable, I am pretty certain *OSX* does not automatically maps to `/usr/lib/dyld` if that load command is not available.

Do you need `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` with `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` load command? I don't think so but that's a good to have either and does not cost much.

Comment: This load command is only needed if the executable is dynamically linked to system dylds or third party dylds.