# Are there any negative side-effects to using -mmacosx-version-min and -segalign flags to reduce padding space in an executable?

Tags: c, macos, assembly

**Background:**

I noticed that if I compile a C program with the `gcc` or `clang` command on macOS 10.15.7 the executable will be around 50 KB no matter how simple the program. In older versions the same program produces one of just 8 KB. I also noticed that most of the extra size are just large contiguous regions of 0 bytes.

The answer at [Why is my hello world binary mostly zeroes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65443939/16217248) explains what the 0 bytes are and how they can be reduced. In newer versions there are more segments in the executable that have to be aligned and their default alignment is larger and this leads to much more padding space in the executable and one can use `-mmacosx-version-min=10.14` and `-Wl,-segalign,0x1000` to force the compiler to use a lesser alignment and get rid of the `__DATA_CONST` section and thus reduce the executable size by up to about 40 KB.

**My new question:**

If using `-mmacosx-version-min=10.14` and `-Wl,-segalign,0x1000` can both reduce the executable to a fraction of the size for simple programs and can allow the executable to run on older versions of macOS too then is there any tradeoff or loss to using them? If so then why? And if not then why are these settings **not** the default?

For example:

- Will the smaller executables without the `__DATA_CONST` segment and smaller segment alignment somehow incur a (significantly) longer startup overhead?
- Are there any machines that use the same executable format but would not be able to run them that could otherwise run the larger executables?

**In summary: For what reason(s) if any might I not want to rotely use `-mmacosx-version-min=10.14` and/or `-Wl,-segalign,0x1000` to optimize all of my executables for size?**