# shrinking the size of a compiled C executable on MacOS

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I've been struggling to reduce the size of my compiled C program.
I made a simple pong program in C with the use of SDL. the program goes something like this:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// drawing functions to make things more orginized
void rect(SDL_Renderer* r,int x,int y,int w,int h);
void line(SDL_Renderer* r,int x,int y,int x2,int y2);
void pixel(SDL_Renderer* r,int x,int y);
void color(SDL_Renderer* rn,int r,int g,int b);
void clear(SDL_Renderer* r);
void update(SDL_Renderer* r);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == 0) {
        SDL_Window* window = NULL;
        SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
        if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(640, 480, 0, &window, &renderer) == 0) {
            SDL_bool done = SDL_FALSE;
            SDL_SetWindowTitle(window,"Pong");
            int h=200;
            int h2=200;
            int move=0;
            blah blah blah...
```

I then compiled the code with this command:

```
gcc -o ~/Desktop/Pong ~/Desktop/pong.c  `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
```

the resulting executable was 34KB. (34,657 bytes) which is pretty good!
but I wanted to see how small I could get it. so I tried some commands:

```
gcc -o ~/Desktop/Pong ~/Desktop/pong.c  `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -O3 -s
gcc -o ~/Desktop/Pong ~/Desktop/pong.c  `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -Oz -O3 -s
some other combinations..
```

they all resulted in the same sized executable. I also tried using `strip`:

```
strip ~/Desktop/Pong
```

but it instead got bigger. (by about 20 bytes)
I've even tried UPX. seemed very reliable. and shrunk it to 8KB! (8208 bytes)

```
upx ~/Desktop/Pong
```

so I opened it up and...

```
zsh: killed     /Users/myname/Desktop/Pong
```

I did have an attempt with tcc (Tiny C Compiler) but the setup was confusing, and it might have limited support with MacOS.

additional information:

1. I am using the gcc compiler
2. I'm on MacOS Monterey
3. I'm using C. not C++

**Edit**: I did try putting the `-Oz` flag first, but It resulted in the same size.

**Edit 2**: maybe my compiler has limits to how small I can get it, but what code optimizations can I make to reduce it more?

Comment: There's limits to what the compiler can do. The rest is up to you to write more minimal code.

Comment: Note that `gcc -o ~/Desktop/Pong ~/Desktop/pong.c sdl2-config --cflags --libs -Oz -O3 -s` is the same as your first `gcc` command because you specified `-O3` after `-Oz`, and `-O3` will be the optimization level used because last-optimization-flag-wins.

Comment: Why are you worried about the size?  34 KiB is pretty small — many programs are far bigger.  For example, `ls -l /bin/ls /usr/bin/clang` shows sizes of 157,376 and 137,616 bytes on my machine.  In my `$HOME/bin` directory, I have executables ranging from about 9 KiB (pretty minimal programs) up to 3,630 KiB.

Comment: [See here](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) for a 45-byte ELF executable (for Linux, not macOS).

Comment: Also [see this](https://gist.github.com/zliuva/1084476). Looks like at least 4096 bytes are needed on macOS.

Comment: To shrink an executable as most as possible, try using [`-Wl,-segalign,0x1000`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65449833/16217248)